# image grid of equal height images but different widths on each row

Tags: css, image

I've searched all over the web and throughout stackoverflow to solve the following problem and although there is tons of posts and feedback on the subject, i cannot find anything that relates specifically to what i'm trying to achieve.

I want to create an image grid/ gallery that is fluid and 100% browser width with responsive images that all resize together. Each 'row of images' has a specific height and all the images within that given row also have the exact same height, but use different widths.

This image better illustrates what i'm trying to achieve-

http://development.revolutionworx.com/image/1.png

The problem i'm getting is that whichever solution i try, i cannot get the images to be the same height no matter what. I would post my code but at this stage i have literally tried dozens and dozens of html and css combinations, none of which work.

On one hand i was led to believe that it's impossible to achieve what i'm looking for using css, however this site appears to have same height images side by side which do resize equally together- http;//www.esquire.co.uk

When i tried masonry.js i also encountered the same problem. Image heights varied according to the width of an image and either shrunk too small within their container or expanded out of their container leaving unequal height boxes side by side. Any pointers or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you had a look at masonry or isotope?

Comment: I have tried masonry and encountered the same issues. I cannot get images of the same height to stay the same height (which each have different widths).

Comment: isotope has the layout option ["fitRows"](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes.html#fitrows) that looks pretty much like what you are describing

Comment: I can use "fitRows" and specify height in px's but then the images aren't fluid and responsive; just static boxes. As such, this also always leaves a gap of white space to the right of the container/ viewport until there's enough room to fit another grid in there. So this doesn't achieve what i'm looking for.